# Migration guide facebook-c#-sdk 4.1 to 5.10

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

is there a migration guide from facebook-c#-sdk 4.11 to 5.10?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some major changes:

1. FacebookApp,FacebookSignedRequest and FacebookSession is moved from Facbook.dll to Facebook.Web.dll but the namespace still remains under "Facebook" (For silverlight and windows phone FacebookApp is in Facebook.dll)
2. FacebookApp still exsits but is hidden from the Visual Studio intellisense and also marked as obsolete. FacebookWebClient is preferred if you are writing new codes, though you can continue to use FacebookApp for existing codes. (If silverlight/wp7 or desktop FacebookClient is preferred.)
3. All the authentication has been moved to use the Facebook OAuth dialog.

You might want to check out this blog post where I mentioned some changes that happened in the first beta of v5. http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-C-SDK-v5-Beta-Internals.aspx

Comment: OK, thanks prabir. I guess there will be complete migration as soon as R5 is released?